# xcopy and xcacls scripting

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

Several years back a couple of great guys helped me create and modify the following script.  I now need to make some modifications to this script to make it run faster and eliminate the 256 character limitation which it currently has.

I thought updating it to use both robocopy (with the `mt` switch) and then perhaps `icacls` would be the best place to start.

Can you help me create a working model that I can test?

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=*" %%F in ('xcopy /S /L \\file1\E$\Data1\*.jpg \ ^| findstr /v File^(s^)')    do (
    xcacls "%%F" /P "Authenticated Users:R" "domain\Administrator:F" "SYSTEM:F" "Photo    Admins:F" /Y
    attrib -a "%%F"
)
```

Comment: you may have better/more answers on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: It might help if you explained what the purpose of the batch was

Comment: The multi-thread `MT` parameter for the `robocopy` command should not make any speed difference because of the list only (do not copy) `L` parameter that is specified.

Comment: I am going to agree with 1r0n1k, can you give us a use/purpose of this and what it currently does for you. I can see that it's copying (using xcopy) all .jpg's and using xcacls to change the authority. Maybe elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

This might still be working you just need to change it to use Icacls and the correct trigger.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=*" %%F in ('xcopy /S /L \\file1\E$\Data1\*.jpg \ ^| findstr /v File^(s^)')    do (
    Icacls "%%F" /grant "Authenticated Users:R" "domain\Administrator:F" "SYSTEM:F" "Photo    Admins:F"
    attrib -a "%%F"
)
```